# Iterators in Java

Tags: java, iterator

So I have a list of integers for each object of a class. 
I am trying to iterate over list of each object, when i encounter a certain condition I move on to the next object and so forth.

My question here is, when i get back to the pervious object which still has unvisited elements in the list how do I remember the iterator for that particular object. Here is the code I have written:

```
void function(Object u, List<Integer> tour, Iterator it) {
Object e;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    e = it.next();
    if (!e.visited) {
        tour.add(e);
        e.visited = true;
        Vertex v = e.otherEnd(e.from);
        v.outgoing++;
        it = v.adj.listIterator(v.outgoing - 1);
        //So instead of re-assigning Iterator it each time is there way //to remember the iterator for each list associated with the object? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store a reference to the Iterator, or are you trying to remember the position in the list? It's unclear as to what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I’m confused as to why you didn’t simply use a second Iterator variable.

Answer (score 0):

Theres three approachs:

Use a for on a new iterator (but it will be only for the second level of your graph and repeated code)

The second one is to change it to recursive.

Or you can do something about having a Stack and be pushing/poping it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map to store the index each iterator has gotten to for an object. You can update the map when you need to switch to a new object and pull from it whenever you come back to it